# How to upload csv to model, validates a field exists in another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, csv, model

I'm working in rails 4.2.6, I have two models - one "project", one "donors".  I have csv uploads working well for both.  "project" contains a field called "donor", when I upload projects csv I want to validate that the "donor" values within that csv exist in the "donor" field of my "donors" model.  (sorry, a little confusing to have a model and column named very similarly)  Anyway, I'm here in project.rb, and obviously it is wrong, I'm just not sure how to connect the validation to another model.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :donor, presence: true


  def self.import(file)
   CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    Project.create! row.to_hash
   end
  end
 end
```

UPDATE:
I'm now here, feel like I'm getting closer, but not quite there yet....

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
validate :validate_donor

  def validate_donor
    if Donors.find_by_donor(donor) == nil
      errors.add(:base, "Donor false")
    end

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      Project.create! row.to_hash
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- in `validate_donor` you seem to be missing an `end`.
- for a one-line conditional i would structure it as simply `errors.add(etc) unless Donors.find_by_donor`

Finally, i've only done this in controllers but a common helper method (eg for current_user) might look like this:

```
def validate_donor
  @donor = Donors.find_by_donor(donor)
  errors.add(etc) unless @donor
end
```

this method would give you a @donor property to save however or add an error to your object (I think- i'm a little rusty).

Comment: Thank you very much. Adding an end fixed it..d'oh!